# How can I add session management to a simple Perl CGI web page?

Tags: perl, session

I have a simple web page that till now didn't need any login. It is programed with Perl CGIs.

I would like to know the steps to add session support in order to have the login information available.

I don't want very complicated methods, because the web page is very simple.

Also I want some recommendations for the technologies/libs that I need to support sessions with Perl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used CGI::Session many, many moons ago.

http://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session

Comment: I suggest linking to perl modules like this to guarantee you get the latest version:  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Session

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Apache::Session](http://metacpan.org/pod/Apache::Session) for session management:

Comment: Note that Apache::Session *doesn't* require apache, mod_perl, etc.